# generate and access a 2d-array with key-value pair using javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to create an array like:

```
var fruits[ ]=[ [1] ["Grapes","mango","orange"] , [2] ["banana"], [A] ["Avocado","Apple"] , [P] ["Pear","Papaya","pomegranate","plum"] ];
```

And accordingly I want to access the above array using key value pairing or something like that.

For example, if I have a dropdown with values:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="P">P</option>
</select>
```

Depending upon my selection, it should display the respective values using a for loop like if I select option "A" then using the for loop it should display the values corresponding to option A ie. Avocado Apple.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Seems you need a switch..case instead of a for loop ... check : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions..but the scenario is that the array is coming from database and it is dynamic..so it can have any value..so cant use switch case..

Comment: If you ned keys, you're better of using an object containing arrays, so you can mix numbers and letters as keys: `var fruits = {"1" : ["Grapes","mango","orange"], "2" : ["banana"], "A" : ["Avocado","Apple"], "P" : ["Pear","Papaya","pomegranate","plum"]}` Then you can loop over the keys and use that key to get the array op options you want to use.

Comment: your *array* is not valid.

Comment: <option> values will be the key...and i can get that into a variable using javascript or jquery..but what to do after that...how to access the corresponding values of that particular key...

Comment: Thanks shilly..that was the type of answer i wanted...but how to do it i dont know...please help me for the above scenario...i googled it but the answers are way different from my case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use object instead of array and bind `change` event on `select` and then use `for` loop.

```js
var fruits = {
  1: ["Grapes", "mango", "orange"],
  2: ["banana"],
  A: ["Avocado", "Apple"],
  P: ["Pear", "Papaya", "pomegranate", "plum"]
}

$('select').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (fruits[val]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fruits[val].length; i++) {
      console.log(fruits[val][i])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="P">P</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can we access them with for loop only without for each loop...bcoz i also want the length of it...like number of values..

Comment: To get length you can just use `console.log(fruits[val].length)`

Comment: thanks...but according to requirement i need for loop instead of for each...bcoz i m working on a part of code which is dynamic and have few modifications in between...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to give arbitrary indexes to array of elements. In that case your **fruits** can be a plain object, rather than being an array.

```
var fruits = {
    1: ["Grapes", "mango", "orange"],   
    2: ["banana"],
    'A': ["avacado", "apple"],
    'P': ["Pear", "Papaya"]
}
```

You can access them any category as follows;

```
fruit[1];    // ["Grapes", "mango", "orange"]
fruit['A'];  // ["avacado", "apple"]
```

Comment: so how to access and display the names using for loop

Comment: @Lalitkumar.annaldas You can check the whole system demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/8jq52em3/

Answer (score 0):

How I would've solved it with an object:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper-select"></div>
<script>
var select,
    keyToUse = "A",
    fruits = {
        "1" : ["Grapes","mango","orange"],
        "2" : ["banana"],
        "A" : ["Avocado","Apple"],
        "P" : ["Pear","Papaya","pomegranate","plum"]
    },
    createOption = function createOption( text ) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = text;
        option.textContent = text;
        return option;
    };
// Select the fruits array we want to use.
// Then loop over it, appending a new option element to our select element.
select = fruits[keyToUse].reduce(function( select, fruitName ) {
    select.appendChild(createOption(fruitName));
    return select;
}, document.createElement('select') );
// Append the newly created select.
document.querySelector('#wrapper-select').appendChild(select);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks ..but i already have the select dropdown ready..it is coming from backend using json...so need not to worry...